# Redirection issue using PK

Tags: django, django-models

I Have a very strange phenomenon
In my app the user Create a project and is redirected to that project detail using its pk. On that project detail page he is asked to create a team and when the team is created he is redirected again to the project detail page but to the wrong pk

for example: I just created a project and I got redirected to .../project/24. I was asked to create a team, I created it but got redirected to ../project/17 any idea why and how to redirect my page to the right URL ?

model.py:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
  class TeamCreate(CreateView):
    model = Team
    fields = ['team_name']
    template_name = 'team_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        valid = super(TeamCreate, self).form_valid(form)
        form.instance.team_hr_admin = self.request.user
        obj = form.save()
        #SELECT * FROM project WHERE user = 'current_user' AND team_id = NULL
        obj2 = Project.objects.get(project_hr_admin=self.request.user, team_id=None)
        obj2.team_id = obj
        obj2.save()
        return valid
        return super(TeamCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        project = Project.objects.get(team_id=self.obj, project_hr_admin=self.request.user)
        return project.get_absolute_url()
```

Comment: Redirecting is not done inside your models.py. Please include your views.py, the problem should be coming from there.

Comment: You should look up the MVC (model-view-controller) pattern, which Django uses. This is a typical approach that will cause problems.

Comment: Hi the redirect come from def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your CreateView is refering to a TeamObject and not project.

You should override the `get_success_url` method:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    project = Porject.objects.get(team_id=self.object, project_hr_admin=self.request.user)
    return project.get_absolute_url()
```

The function called was the `get_absolute_url` of your Team model. So you're calling the project detail view but with the team pk => you get a random project assuming there's a project with a pk which has the same value as your project or, the pk you're sending doesn't exist and you'll have a 404 error (pk doesn't exist).

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk})
```

That's the one in your Team model, but you call ProjectDetails. So here, self.pk is Teaminstance.pk.

What I do in the code i gave you is to call the `get_absolute_url` of the project instance.

But as told in the other answer, you should remove or change your `get_absolute_url` of your team model.

Comment: Great great great explanation !  It is very clear to me now ! THx you so much Bestasttung for your help and clear explanation ;)

Comment: Bestasttung I got "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define"

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolut
e_url method on the Model. any idea ?

Comment: welll try to print or put a ```import pdb; pdb.set_trace()``` before the return in get_success_url to see if ```project``` is well found and then check what ```project.get_absolute_url()``` return.

Comment: I got :
    url = self.object.get_absolute_url()
AttributeError: 'Team' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'

Comment: where did you add the ```get_success_url``` method?

Comment: I replace the get_absolute_url in the team model by your get_success_url

Comment: No get_success_url is a method in the CreateView :). Not in your model.
Add this method in the TeamCreate (the view).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154446/discussion-between-ben2pop-and-bestasttung).

Comment: I edited the my Team create view but now I get AttributeError: 'TeamCreate' object has no attribute 'obj'

Answer (score 0):

```
class Team(models.Model):  

    # ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk})
                                                                      ^^^^^^^
```

Here, the wrong `pk` will be delived. Thx to @Bestasttung for clarification

Comment: No because he wants to redirect to the project page. But you're right, the problem is he's redirecting to a project but with the team pk. That's actually a chance he didn't have an error 'wrong pk'